# VBA fire event on empty HTML div

Tags: excel, vba

I try to automate some manual processes by using VBA automation. One of them is to click on a  element that has an empty content and at the moment I am not able to figure out how to deal with it

The HTML code that I am trying to click on:

```html
<div id="searchcombobox-1077-triggerWrap" data-ref="triggerWrap" class="x-form-trigger-wrap x-form-trigger-wrap-toolbar">
    <div id="searchcombobox-1077-inputWrap" data-ref="inputWrap" class="x-form-text-wrap x-form-text-wrap-toolbar">
        <input id="searchcombobox-1077-inputEl" data-ref="inputEl" type="text" role="combobox" size="1" name="searchcombobox-1077-inputEl" placeholder="Account Number" tabindex="-1" class="x-form-field x-form-text x-form-text-toolbar " autocomplete="off" componentid="searchcombobox-1077">
    </div>
    <div id="searchcombobox-1077-trigger-picker" class="x-form-trigger x-form-trigger-toolbar x-form-search-trigger x-form-search-trigger-toolbar "></div>
</div>
```

The VBA code used is:

```
HTMLDoc.getElementById("searchcombobox-1077-inputEl").Value = '11xx111'

Set click_el = HTMLDoc.querySelector("#searchcombobox-1077-trigger-picker")

With click_el
    .Focus
    .FireEvent "onclick"
End With
```

What should be the approach that I need to take into consideration since the div element that I need to click on is empty?

Thanks,

Comment: What is happening? Are you getting any error messages? If you are, on which line? Are you certain you have the right div?

Comment: Look at potentially attaching the event as shown: https://codedocu.com/office-365/access/controls/web-browser/vba,-htmlselect_colon_-fireevent-onchange-or-dispatchevent?1890

Comment: There is no error, the element is the correct one, clicking on it in the browser does what is supposed to do but using VBA it does not work..